# Creating single line chart from comparable data but with different horizontal extents

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I'm trying to create a line chart showing two sets of data (i.e. two lines) that span the same range. In this case the horizontal axis is a date range. However, one set (A) has multiple entries spanning a single entry for the other dataset (B).

To clarify, my horizontal axis will span 135 - 255, however dataset B record just 135 where as A can record decimals of 135 up to 136 (and so on).

Is there away to set the horizontal axis so dataset B is "stretched" across the age range, rather than displaying like the image below.

[image: Example chart]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a Line Chart, which treats X values as non-numeric labels, not as values, and which uses the same labels for all series in the chart, make an XY Scatter chart, using one of the options that connects points with straight lines.